# deploying a 2-project solution (desktop and web) in windows7

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I require to deploy in a **windows7-running PC** a **C#** solution which basically consists of two projects: **A** and **B**. A is a desktop application (**Windows Forms Application**) and B is a REST service application (**asp.net Web-API**).
I've the following questions regarding this solution's **deployment**:
**1)** should I install application A in windows **Startup** folder in order to start up this application as soon as the PC is initiated ?
**2)** should I create a folder to store B and then let **IIS** web-server know of its existence ? If so, should I also put this folder int the Startup folder if I want it to start when the PC is initiated ? 
**3)** If (1) and (3) are correct, is there any advantages in developing in **a single** solution **two different projects** (a desktop project and a web project) in visual studio, instead of doing it in two different solutions ? (I mean their deployment is by nature different)

**Thanks in advance for any comments !**

Comment: where will be B running? On PC or on a server?

Comment: both applications will run on a PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is OK to put program A into startup if you want it to run every time you start your computer. For B, you are right that you need to store it in a folder and host it at IIS. You can set "Start Automatically" property to be true for the site and check "Start Immediately" for the related application pool, which enable auto start after reboot PC.

I think there are two reasons to put different projects into one solution.

1. Better structure to group related applications into one solution
2. Different projects can better share/reuse code. For example, there
   are two projects sharing the same processDbData function. You can
   put it in a class library in the same solution and both the projects
   can call it. When any code change needed for proecessDbData, you only need
   to modify one place. But if you separate the projects into different
   solutions, this can be more complex.

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks a lot for your response ! it's pretty helpful for me.